# how to find supervisor name in sql

Tags: sql

Can someone help me to understand where is the issue with below code please.
There are two schemas

```
lecturer (staffid (pk), name, school, office)
student(studentid(pk), name, supervisor)
```

supervisor referenced staffid

now we need to find all students supervised by Mike

I wrote it as follow

```
SELECT studentid
FROM student,lecturer
WHERE supervisor=staffid AND
lecturer.name = "mike"
```

maybe this is a simple issue but I guess I am missing the concept here.
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: It's hard to tell without the error message, but maybe fully qualify your `join` columns: `WHERE <table_name>.supervisor = <table_name>.staffid`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete error message you get (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If supervisor is a foreign key on staffid then the logic seems fine.

But these days you should use the JOIN syntax

```
SELECT s.studentid, s.name
FROM student AS s
JOIN lecturer AS l
  ON l.staffid = s.supervisor
WHERE l.name = 'Mike'
```

And a literal for a CHAR/VARCHAR should be in single-quotes.
There's no "Mike" column in those tables.

Comment: the result will be the same as in query from question + name column. It is just another way to get the same data. don't think that OP ask about that

Comment: Why a literal for a CHAR/VARCHAR should be in single-quotes? How do you know that? OP didn't specify what RDBMS in use

Comment: @RomanMarusyk: `"mike"` in the question refers to a column name, whereas `'Mike'` in this answer refers to a string constant. Using a non-existing column name will lead to an error  and it's likely that this is the error that Misno gets. As far as the "why" is concerned: this is how string literals are defined in the SQL standard and as long as the question is only tagged with `sql` we should assume that a standard compliant database is used.